# Why the JInterFrame not resizing?

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I am creating one java Application which includes the JDesktopPane and JInternalFrame.

And I am using GridLayOut to set JInternalFrame

The Issue is I can't resize the JInternalFrame as per the GridLayout size

Below is One Screen Shot of Application
[image]

I want the JInnernalFrame as the grid size.

Please do help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `JInternalFrame`s are suppose to be added to and managed by a `JDesktopPane`

Take a look at [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for more details

`JDesktopPane` isn't suppose to have a layout manager, the `GridLayout` is taking control and making decision about how the `JInternalFrame` should be managed.

Simple answer is, don't use a layout manager with a `JDesktopPane`.  Instead use `JInternalFrame#pack` to size the frames, `setLocation` to place it and don't forget to make it visible

> I want the JInnernalFrame as the grid size

Either don't use `JInternalFrame`s this way, or provide functionality that can mimic this when you want it. Layout managers tend to be to rigid for providing both these functionalities